# how to search for a fixed value when clicked on search button from a list which is already retrieved from database using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using a search functionality to get the searched records from the list which is already retrieved from database and populated in html page,I am getting the filtered search but not complete search from the list in controller. I need  the fixed value result to be showed when clicked on search button(eg.I should not get 'John' when searched for 'J',i should get the exact value what i search),Can any one help me out.
**This is my piece of HTML code.**

```
<ul class="col-sm-11 col-xs-12 searchFields">
                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><span class="col-xs-12">TIN</span><input type="text" ng-model="data.providerTin" ng-keyup="formatTin($event)"  ng-trim="false" ng-blur="clearError()" id="tinElem" placeholder="TIN" maxlength="11" autofocus /></li>
                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><span class="col-xs-12">Last Name</span><input type="text" ng-model="data.providerFullLastName" ng-keyup="formatLast($event)" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="20" /></li>
                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><span class="col-xs-12">First Name</span><input type="text" ng-model="data.providerFirstName" ng-keyup="formatFirst($event)" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="12" /></li>
                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><span class="col-xs-12">City</span><input type="text" ng-model="data.prvdAdrCityNm" ng-keyup="formatCity($event)" placeholder="City" maxlength="21" /></li>
                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><span class="col-xs-12">State</span><input type="text" ng-model="data.prvdAdrStCd" ng-keyup="formatState($event)" ng-trim="false" ng-blur="clearError()" placeholder="State" maxlength=2 /></li>
                    <li class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><span class="col-xs-12">Phone</span><input type="text" ng-model="provider.prvdTelNum" ng-keyup="formatPhone($event)" ng-blur="clearError()" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" onkeydown="javascript:backspacerDOWN(this,event);" onkeyup="javascript:backspacerUP(this,event);" maxlength="14" required /></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="col-md-1  col-sm-4 searchBlock">

                    <button class="searchBtn" type="button" id="searchBtn" ng-click="">Search</button>

                </div>


<tr  ng-repeat= "data in recommendatnList| filter:searchd"  >
                        <td><a href="#/viewPrvdDtlPage/{{data.providerId}}" class="openLink">{{data.providerTin}}</a></td>
                        <td>{{data.providerFullLastName}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.providerFirstName}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.providerPracticeName}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.prvdAdrCityNm}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.prvdAdrStCd}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.prvdAdrXpndZipCd}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.measure}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.grade}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.measurePaid}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.totalPaid}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.noOfLettrsAnyMeasure}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.noOfLettrsRecommMeasure}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.currClaimAnyMeasure}}</td>
                        <td>{{data.currClaimCurrRecomm}}</td>
                        <td class="interventTblecol"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.letter" ng-model="data.letter"></td>
                        <td class="interventTblecol"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.mcr" ng-model="data.mcr"></td>
                        <td class="interventTblecol"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.fcr" ng-model="data.fcr"></td>
                        <td class="interventTblecol"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.siu" ng-model="data.siu"></td>
                        <td class="interventTblecol"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.removeClaimRvw" ng-model="data.removeClaimRvw" ></td>
                        <td class="interventTblecol"><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="data.flag" ng-model="data.flag"></td>

        </tr>
```

**and this is my Controller**

```
angular.module('admApp').controller(
    "RecommendationCtrl",
    [
            '$scope',
            '$stateParams',
            'RecommendationService',
            function($scope, $stateParams, RecommendationService) {

                RecommendationService.fetchRecommendatns().then(function(data) {
                    alert("data"+JSON.stringify(data));
                    $scope.recommendatnList=data;

                });
```

Comment: can you please try to re-explain, and include definition of the `searchd`filter. You got some data and you want to filter them on a press of a button .... and

Answer (score 0):

That is some odd thing to request.

TL;DR: **[PLUNKR example on Explicit Filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/yhmVc2NIE7Z0f5xgxEC3?p=preview)** What i wrote below, is for a bit more beginners who are struggling with angularjs.

But Basically you are trying to create an explicit filter?

Like if we have

```
  $scope.records =  [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                     {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                     {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                     {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                     {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                     {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}];
```

You would want that J will present nothing 
and John would present `name:John, Phone: 555-1276` ?

If that is the case you need to use anuglarjs custom filters.

I've created a plunker for that reason:
**[Working Explicit Filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/yhmVc2NIE7Z0f5xgxEC3?p=preview)** which is using the same records as above.

The filter method is rather not that smart but I'll give you a short explanation about it :

```
newApp.filter('explicitSearch',function(){

  //AngularJS -> declaring a new filter in our newApp module.

  return function(items, string){  
  //The parameters here: well the first parameter in your filter return function would always be the data you are referring to.
  //The second parameter would be the argument that you are passing to the filter,

  //Example : Looks like so <tr ng-repeat='friend in friends | filterName:filterSecondParam'>

     var filtered = [];
    //This array, is going to be our filtered results.


     //This is simple JS code, basically iterate over the data the filter have passed, what if you find something that is explicitly equal, add it to our filtered array.
         for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (item.name === string) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
      if(item.phone === string){
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    }
    return filtered;
  }

});
```

**Use upon HTML:**

```
 <body ng-controller='Ctrl'>
  Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat='record in records | explicitSearch:searchText '>
                <td>{{record.name}}</td>
                <td>{{record.phone}}></td>                

            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </body>
```